# SQL Server - active monitoring and alerts

Tags: sql-server

We occasionally experience problems with blocks on the database which prevents other users from editing the table. Whenever we realize that something went wrong we usually run `sp_who2` sys procedure in order to check BlkBy column and find `SPID` which blocks the database.

Now we are thinking about some early warning system which will notify us about the block before the others.

Is there any feature in SQL Server which can constantly monitor the situation and alert us once there are more than 3 blocks on specific database?

**IMPORTANT**: we would like to *avoid* creating a job which does that.

I've checked multiple forums and articles already, but couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Thank you all for the help.

Cheers

Comment: Why do you have problems with blocking? Maybe you should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to actively monitor the locks however preventing it may be possible by creating triggering events?  Without knowing your desired outcomes its hard to say!

[Create Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)